# NEC valuestarにCentOS7がインストールできない

Tags: linux, centos

NEC valuestarにCentOS7をDVD(ISOイメージ）からインストールしようとすると、

```
not enough memory to load specified image
```

が出力され、BOOT：プロンプトが表示されますが、それ以降進めることができません。

なお、Ubuntuはインストールできており、該当PCの実メモリは２GBです。

Comment: 具体的な機種名もしくは型番が提示されると何かわかるかもしれません。

Comment: NEC valuestar　型番 PC-VN770BS6B
bios version 497A0200です。

Answer (score 1):

ISOをDVDに焼いて上記のエラーが発生している場合は、BIOSの設定画面を開いてみてください。

チップセット関連のメニューに`Memory Hole At 15M-16M`という項目はあるでしょうか。
もしこの設定が`Enabled`になっていた場合は`Disabled`に変更することで解決する可能性があるようです。
[`LinuxQuestion.org`の類似懸案コメント](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/not-enough-memory-to-load-specified-image-898197/#post4454641)

`Memory Hole At 15M-16M`の意味について、[BIOSの教科書](http://www.nas.ne.jp/nas/members/Library/bios/table/chipset.html)というサイトに説明がありましたので転載します。

> ISAバスを高速化するための設定です。通常は[Disabled]に設定します。[Enabled]にすると、16MB以上の領域にアクセスできなくなってしまいます。

もしもDVD作成可能なISOイメージからブート用USBを作成した場合に質問のエラーが発生している場合は、[Qiitaの類似記事](https://qiita.com/kzt_tateyama/items/fa5465a0e7516c935b4c)に記載されている以下の操作を試してみてください。

1. `boot:`の後に`mem=2048M`を入力してEnterを押す
2. 上記の操作後に`Could not find kernel image: mem=2048M`というエラーが出る場合はブート用USB作成ツールを見直す
   (『UNetbootin』ではなく『Win32 Disk Imager』を利用する)

今回のご質問ではDVDと明記されているので後者は的外れな回答と予想しますが、エラー内容で検索をかけたところUSBブートの例も多かったので記載いたしました。

Comment: 詳細な情報、ありがとうございます。
残念ながら、
Memory Hole At 15M-16M
という項目はありませんでした。